# Space does not recognize as special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression to match combination of Lower case upper case and special characters.

```
 var regLowerUpperSpecilaCase = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{7,50}$/;
```

Everything seems fine but when i put a space along with the lowercase uppercase and special character it does not recognize and failed.

```
inputtxt='aS!a uiuiqw';
inputtxt.match(regLowerUpperSpecilaCase)
```

Actually i want to match everything instead of digit. but combination must have lower case, upper case and special characters.

Can anybody put some light on it.

Comment: What else do you expect? `(?!.*\s)` will fail the regex if there is a space in the input.

Comment: Back to the core of the question: what are you, exactly, trying to do?

Comment: i just want to match a combination of lower case upper case and special character which has minimum length 7 and maximum 50 @Robin

Comment: What's a special character? Please edit your question to explain it.

Comment: Sorry i understand. but i want to allow space also along with this. what will be the correction? @Robin

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. You want to match a string composed of: uppercase, lowercase, and... what else? Everything is fine? Do you allow digits? What should be forbidden?

Comment: characters not in [a-z][A-Z][0-9] and line break/newline character will be allowed in the case of special. @Robin

Comment: So you want to allow character in `[a-z]` AND characters not in `[a-z]`? Do you see where that might go wrong?

Comment: Please, give examples of what you want to match and what you don't want to match.

Comment: i want to match aS! as|:,.
What should i do.

Comment: sort of everything instead of digit. but combination must have lower case upper case and special characters

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood, you want to validate a string with at least a lowercase, at least an uppercase, and at least something else (but no digit).

If everything which is not a letter or a digit is a special character (so a space is a special character), try

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])[^0-9]+$
```

If that doesn't suit you, please, *please*, give examples of strings that should match or shouldn't match. A lot of them. By editing your question.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, this is what you need:

```
var myregexp = /^(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[A-Z]+)(?=.*[ !"#$%&\/()=?@.£§€{[\]}]+)(^.{7,50}$)$/;
```

It will need a combination of, at least, one uppercase, lowercase and special character (including space), with a minimum length of 7 and maximum of 50 characters to validate.

http://regex101.com/r/pK0eA8

Comment: i am little new to regex. i just copy this and have some confusion with it. it will be helpful if you please tell me what does (?!.*\s) do? @Tuga

Comment: It doesn't match `any character` followed by white spaces or line breaks.

Comment: does white space is a special character? Actually i just want to match a combination of lower case upper case and special character which has minimum length 7 and maximum 50 @Tuga

Comment: Please define special.

Comment: but i want to allow space

Comment: which characters do you want to allow ? a-z space and 0-9 ?

Comment: characters not in [a-z][A-Z][0-9] and line break/newline character will be allowed in the case of special

Comment: @Tuga: I don't believe the non-capturing groups are necessary.

Comment: @Robin, they don't but they help me to read my code clearly. I've removed them. tks for pointing that anyway.